# Joining sentences to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to export a dataframe to csv. But on top of it, I would like to print the date of the dataframe to produce the following result in the csv file. How can I join the string sentence to the dataframe so that I can export it together to csv?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

today1=dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
print('This dataframe is created on ',today1)
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[3,4]})
print(df)
df.to_csv('temp.csv')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_csv` accepts a filehandle as input. So write your first line, then call `to_csv` with the same handle:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

today1=dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[3,4]})
with open("temp.csv","w") as f:
    f.write('This dataframe is created on {}\n'.format(today1))
    df.to_csv(f)
```

when you read the data back just do the same with `pd.read_csv()`:

```
with open("temp.csv","r") as f:
    date_line = next(f)
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `to_csv` line in your code, then run it in a terminal window as below:

```
python code.py >> temp.csv
```

Your `print` instructions will be printed in temp.csv. The output file is:

```
('This dataframe is created on ', '20161220')
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Not sure if it works in every OS though.